# The 'base' parameter being passed into safe_join(base, *paths) ends with a '/' 

Tags: django

First time posting so I hope I'm doing this right.

I'm creating a custom admin form in "myapp/admin.py", and I'm using the line :  `default_storage.exists('/usr/tmp/somefile.txt')`.

However, `exists()` is throwing a `SuspiciousOperation` exception.  I took a look into it and the problem seems to be coming from `safe_join(base, *paths)` in "_os.py".

It turns out the base paramenter is being set to `'/'` and this breaks the following code in `safe_join()` :

```
if not normcase(final_path).startswith(normcase(base_path)) \
  or final_path[base_path_len:base_path_len+1] not in ('', sep):
    raise ValueError('The joined path (%s) is located outside of the base '
                     'path component (%s)' % (final_path, base_path))
```

I don't run into this problem when I use `default_storage.exists()` in `manage.py shell`.  Also, I'm using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `default_storage.location`?

Comment: `default_storage.location` is just `'/'` - not sure if that's what I should be expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like something is not set up correctly in your settings.py
The possible reason you are seeing that `SuspiciousOperation` exception is because your default_storage.location is set to `/` root, and I would think having access to the root of your filesystem is definitely suspicious.

You may want to check that you have set `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings.py to something reasonable as a location for storage:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#media-root

It seems that default_storage.location value derives from the MEDIA_ROOT? For me, it is equal to that value. When I try to do default_storage.exists() on a path that lives higher than the location, it raises that exception as well.